# vb.net variable value store

Tags: vb.net, string, variables

vb.net

```
Dim a As Integer = 1
Dim b, c As String

TextBox1.Text = 36

b = "TextBox1.Text" 

c = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I want to Store `TextBox1` Value (which is 36) to variable `c`.

Please fill the last Line (which marks As XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX on the above program last line).

Comment: I don't understand. What's stopping you from completing that line?

Comment: Is this question from some online test or what?

Comment: @Dikesh: Not much of a test if it is.

Comment: I think you Do not understand my problem

Please See carefully

        Dim a As Integer = 2

        Dim b, c As String

        b = "Label"

        b = b & a & ".Text"

        

        Label5.Text = val(c)




'last line is not correct

Comment: I think you do not know how to formulate a question.

Comment: I am First time user, Just Registered one hour ego

Comment: Your comment code does not agree with your question.

Comment: Dear Sir ( The Blue Dog)

Please Solve My Problem And Give Me The Correct Code

Actually the value of b = TextBox1.Text It Is generated Text
so I can't put directly c = TextBox1.Text

Comment: Why not? You're referring to something different in the comments, please try to improve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I see what you are trying to do -  you want to get the value from a textbox on your form, using a dynamically generated name for the textbox control, correct?

This will do what you want:

```
Dim a As Integer = 1
Dim b, c As String

TextBox1.Text = 36

b = "TextBox" & a.ToString 'b = "Textbox1"

c = Me.Controls(b).Text 'c = 36
```

It's also worth adding some error checking in case a textbox with the dynamically generated name doesn't actually exist on the form:

```
If Me.Controls(b) IsNot Nothing Then
    c = Me.Controls(b).Text 'c = 36
Else
    'textbox control doesn't exist...
End If
```

Comment: @AdhirchMondal: No problem at all, I'm glad I could help. I realise that English may not be your first language, but please try and phrase your questions more accurately in the future; it will help you get the answers you need without us having to guess what it is that you actually want. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Dim a, inc As Integer
        Dim bb As String = "Label"    
        Dim it As String = "Item"    
        a = pc
        For value As Integer = 1 To a
        inc = 52
        inc = inc + value
        it = it & value.ToString   
        tmp_item = it & ".Text"
        bb = bb & inc
        b = Me.Controls(bb).Text
        MsgBox(b)
      Next


Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please Solve this problem And give me the exact code